# Password, Password_Confirmation ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, testing, passwords

I'm working through the Rails Tutorial and I've gotten stuck. I'm trying to use a password and password_confirmation.

I'm getting the error(s):

```
  15) User when password confirmation is nil 
 Failure/Error: @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
 ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
   Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password, password_confirmation
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:5:in `new'
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.21758 seconds
25 examples, 15 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:8 # User 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:9 # User 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:10 # User 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:11 # User 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:12 # User 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:14 # User 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:17 # User when name is not present 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:21 # User when name is too long 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:25 # User when email format is invalid should be invalid
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:33 # User when email format is invalid when email format is valid should be valid
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:47 # User when email address is already taken 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:55 # User when email address is already taken 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:59 # User when password is not present 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:63 # User when password doesn't match confirmation 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:67 # User when password confirmation is nil
```

All of the errors are for the same reason.

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: {     case_sensitive: false }
  #has_secure_password
  has_many :event
end
```

user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
    before do
        @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
    end
    subject { @user }
    it { should respond_to(:name) }
    it { should respond_to(:email) }
    it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
    it { should respond_to(:password) }
    it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `password, :password_confirmation` to `attr_accessible` in `user.rb`

```
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

`attr_accessible` method takes list of attributes to be accessible. the other attribute will be protected see [Mass Assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/security.html#mass-assignment) for the reason.

Comment: People on here are too  quick I was just about to answer that! HA